# matrix rank over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, matrix-rank

Let $M$ be a square matrix over finite field $\Bbb F_p$. Let $N$ be the matrix over $\Bbb F_p$ obtained replacing every non-zero entry of $M$ by $1$.

Is $Rank(N)\leq Rank(M)^{f_p}$? for some constant $f_p$?

Answer (score 3):

**In response to the original question:**

Consider the following matrix in $\Bbb F_p$ with $p>2$:
$$
M = \pmatrix{
1&-1&0\\
0&1&-1\\
-1&0&1},
N = \pmatrix{
1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
1&0&1}
$$
Note that $\det(N) = 2$, but $M$ has a non-zero kernel.  So, $N$ has rank $3$, but the $M$ has rank $2$.

So, for the new question: we know that if an $f_p$ exists, we have $f_p>1$ when $p>2$.

---

For an arbitrary $n$: let $I_n$ denote the identity matrix, and let $J_n$ denote the permutation matrix
$$
J_n = 
\pmatrix{
&1\\
&&1\\
&&&\ddots\\
&&&&1\\
1
}
$$
We note that $I_n - J_n$ is always singular, and that $I_n + J_n$ has eigenvalues $1 + \omega$, where $\omega$ is any solution to $\omega^n = 1$.

Note that $I_j + J_n$ is singular when $n$ is even.

It may be useful to consider the case $n = kp$, where $k$ is odd (in these cases, the eigenvalues are easy to determine).

Comment: See my latest edit; I mistyped before

Comment: It is clear, then, that if such an $f_p$ exists, it can't be $1$ except when $p = 2$.

Comment: det(N) = 1.1.1 - (1)(-1)=2 and det(M)= 1- (-1)(-1)=0

Comment: ok question is: is there f_p?

Comment: Well, that's your new question. I'll see if I think of something.